# Global indexes while renaming the partition name

Tags: oracle11g, indexing, data-partitioning

I have a existing table with some indexes in it. I am going to do partitioning of that table using dbms redefinition. I also have to rename the partition names every 24 hours. 
Is there any problem in global indexes after I rename the partition names. Please reply.

Is it mandatory to have a primary key to perform interval partitioning?

I am using oracle 11g

Comment: "I also have to rename the partition names every 24 hours." - that's a _really_ strange thing to do. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because in interval partitioning, you get system generated partition names(like SYS41,SYS42,etc). I have to rename these names to custom names(some what like 14-jan-2013).

Comment: Why do you need specific names for the partitions though?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming partitions doesn't affect index status, global or otherwise. They stay valid if they were valid before the rename.

You don't need a primary key for interval partitioning. The constraints are the same as for range partitioning, with some restrictions. See [Interval Partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm#autoId29) in the concepts guide:

> - You can only specify one partitioning key column, and it must be of NUMBER or DATE type.
> - Interval partitioning is not supported for index-organized tables.
> - You cannot create a domain index on an interval-partitioned table.

Note that the names for the partitions created automatically on an interval-partitioned table are system-generated. You can rename them after they've been created, but you cannot, in 11gR2, have them created with a name of your choice.

Comment: Post a separate question for that. If it's about rdbms_redefinition stuff, you should consider posting on dba.stackexchange.com rather than here. (But would be ok here too.)

Comment: @user1947949: that's not how this site works. You asked a specific question and got an answer. Now you have a separate question, so ask a separate question to get a specific answer.

Comment: oh!okay. Thanks. I have posted a seprate question. I am new here. Thanks for helping.